# Predicates in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I have ran into this problem, i have a WP8 application, and i want to support WP7, so i'm Copy/Pasting the code, and have noticed that:

```
Predicate<Contact> contactFinder = (Contact p) => { return p.Id == contact.Id; };
MyContactsList.Contacts.Exists(contactFinder) != true
```

Method .Exists() doesn't exist on WP7, is there a workaround? Or i will have to go through all elements and check their ID? Like:

```
foreach ( Contact a in MyContactsList.Contacts )
{
    if (a.id!=id)
    enter code here
}
```

It will hang up the system, because i have about 1400+ contacts...

Comment: What is the type of `MyContactsList` and `MyContactsList.Contacts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq instead:

```
Func<Contact, bool> contactFinder = p =>p.Id == contact.Id;
MyContactsList.Contacts.Any(contactFinder)
```

Just make sure you've added `using System.Linq;` on top of your file.

Also, regarding your remark:

> It will hang up the system, because i have about 1400+ contacts...

It won't change anything. Under the hood, the `Exists` method does exactly the same thing as your foreach loop.

Comment: @Cheese Linq does the same thing as the `Exists` method, and will therefore work at pretty much the same speed